# Mouse event handling in a node and its children

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bunch of nodes in my svg container. Each node has two children: a circle and a text label, so that the label is centered inside the circle.

```
var nodes = d3.select("#main").selectAll("g.node");
var circles = nodes.append("circle");
var labels = nodes.append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle");
```

On mouse hover, I perform some additional logic, e.g.

```
nodes.on('mouseover', function () {
    console.log('on mouse over');
})
.on('mouseout', function () {
    console.log('on mouse out');
});
```

Now, the problem is that apparently, the mouse events in node and its child label are treated separately: when I enter the circle with the mouse cursor, the `mouseover` event is triggered. When I then move the cursor above the text label, suddenly the `mouseover` event is triggered like when the cursor would leave the circle and another `mouseover` event starts.

Is there a possibility to "merge" the event handling of node and its child label so that no new `mouseover` event starts when I hover over the text while still being inside the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: add attribute `pointer-events` with value `none` to forbid mouse events:

```
var labels = nodes
    .append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("pointer-events", "none");
```